# How to compress google cloud storage files ? google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-storage

I am using google app engine (python2.7), I save the user images in the cloud storage .

I want to give the user option to download her/his images in zip file.

is there any code that I could use, to select several images from cloud storage , compress them and download them as zip file.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python), which contains the sample code to create a zip archive of GCS images and other files and to download the zip file.

To run the sample code in the SDK use: `http://localhost:8080/blob_upload`
This code uploads files to GCS, which will be added to the archive for download.

blobarchive() in blob_files.py creates the zip archive.